# wordpress preg_match_all() error, use preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have to use the preg_replace_callback function instead of the preg_match_all function, but my research on this issue has not yielded any results. Please can you help me on how to fix my codes below?

```
$content_post = get_post($id);

$content = $content_post->post_content;

$html_content = wpautop( $content );

preg_match_all('#<!--part_name:(.*?)-->#Ssie',$html_content,$PartCount);

preg_match_all('#<!--part_name:.*?-->(.*?)<!--nextpage-->#Ssie',$html_content,$PartEmbed);
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace_callback() is kind of a tricky function.  Documentation for it is here:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php  Here's an example:

```
$oldString ='
<!--part_name:PartName11-->
Description of the part etc...
<br>
<!--part_name:PartName22-->
Description of the next part etc...
<br>
<!--part_name:PartName33-->
Description of the last part etc...
<br>
';

function unComment ($matches){
    $visible = str_replace('<!--', '', $matches[0]);
    $visible = str_replace('-->', '', $visible);
    return $visible;
}

$newString = preg_replace_callback('#<!--part_name:(.*?)-->#', 'unComment', $oldString);

echo '<p>'.$newString.'</p>';
```

which displays:

```
part_name:PartName11 Description of the part etc...
part_name:PartName22 Description of the next part etc...
part_name:PartName33 Description of the last part etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

MyString Example

```
<!--part_name:Part - 1,en, Slow-->

Frame

<!--nextpage--><!--part_name:Part - 2,tr,Fast-->

Frame

<!--nextpage--><!--part_name:Part - 3,en,FHD-->

Frame

<!--nextpage-->
```

I want to get the following parameters in an array.

**Part - 1,en, Slow**

With the above code, all parameters are listed one under the other and I cannot get the data exactly as I want.